# Automatically commit in git through python

Tags: python, git, heroku

I want to write a service that using heroku to manage my git repos automatically, but I don't know how to using git in heroku&python. Just simple process and simple push.

That is to say, i don't want to manage heroku's git, but using heroku to manage another git repo/repos.

Is there exist a standard procedure to do all of this? in a mature and safe (in some extent) way.

Also, can you experienced smart guys tell me some python mudule or codes about this?

I have read Gitpython, gitosis, but I don't think they are suitable.

Comment: Naively, can't you run `git commit -m "Message"` and `git push`?

Comment: @Blender At first, I want to host my service to diff. PaaS. And, Heroku just provide a service of python, I don't think it can run this primitive command. 
So I try to find a method to get around of this in heroku.

Comment: Just curious, but in what ways is gitpython unsuitable?

Comment: @peppergrower Gitpython using git as a backend. normally, heroku, just only provide a pure python platform. Means it don't include a git backend. It will raise some error.

Answer (score 1):

dulwich is a re-implement of git in python, which can run on some cloud PaaS, It's a really good idea to solve this.

http://www.samba.org/~jelmer/dulwich/